# Return name or text using Else statement?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, tuples, average

I have a Python list of people with names, age and gender:

```
people = [('John', 36, 'M'), ('Rachel', 24, 'F'), ('Deardrie', 78, 'F'), ('Ahmed', 17, 'M'), ('Sienna', 14, 'F')]
```

I have written some code that pulls back the average age of all males ('M'):

```
def average_age(members,gender):
    return sum([member[1] for member in people if member[2] == "M"])/2
```

This returns the expected result:

```
average_age(people, 'M')
26.5
```

However, if I was to write `average_age(people, 'Z')` I would like it to return the result statement to return `'No matches found.'` At the moment, it still returns 26.5.

I have tried putting an else statement within the code but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Also your code entirely ignores the gender argument passed in and always looks for entries with 'M'. you need to use `gender` rather than `"M"` in the sum function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an if statement within the function to ensure the gender passed to the function is either "M" or "F"

```
def average_age(members,gender):
    if gender not in ["F","M"]:
      return 'No matches found.'
    else:
     return sum([member[1] for member in people if member[2] == gender])/2
```

Comment: Thanks so much - I didn't even think of adding the F!